# Автореконнект бота в случае краша [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

У меня есть бот в Discord'е, и мне нужно в случае его краша не перезапускать бота вручную, а чтобы он сам реконнектился, примерно так я и сделал, но это совсем не то что мне надо:

```
setInterval(()=>{
  client.login("токен")
},100)
```

Comment: А нельзя отлавливать exception через try/catch и не допускать краша бота???

Comment: я знаю что есть try catch, но мне нужно чтобы если был краш бота оно автоматом зареконектило его

Comment: Для таких случаев есть: `nodemon`, `forever`, `pm2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильным решением данной задачи будет отлов всех `exception` и предотвращения краша самого приложения. Написав тесты и построив правильную архитектуру приложения вы не задумаетесь об автореконнекте.

Есть альтернативный способ, использование модуля [**`Forever`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

---

Тестовый проект выглядит следующим образом:

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-crash-auto-restart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "forever -s index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "forever": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

---

### index.js

```
setTimeout(() => {
    throw 'My exception';
}, 5000);
```

---

### Запуск через консоль

```
npm run start
```

---

### Результат вывода консоли через 15 секунд работы

```
C:\OSPanel\domains\app-crash-auto-restart>npm run start

> app-crash-auto-restart@1.0.0 start C:\OSPanel\domains\app-crash-auto-restart
> forever -s index.js

error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #1
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #2
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #3
```